# Unable to upload file to S3 Bucket using aws-java-sdk

Tags: aws-java-sdk, spring-cloud-aws

I have a spring boot application which uploads files to S3 bucket.
I am receiving the following error whenever the application tries to upload a file. The stack trace is a huge one. So I am providing only a part of it.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Socket not created by this factory
at org.apache.http.util.Asserts.check(Asserts.java:34) ~[httpcore-4.4.6.jar:4.4.6]
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.isSecure(SSLSocketFactory.java:435) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:186) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
```

I am using the following dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.123</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have even tried with

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

But sill getting the same type of error

I have tried using both TransferManager as well as putObject() method from AmazonS3 but with same error.

The application was running well a few days back and the error has started to come only very recently.

Comment: Better if you provide the entire stacktrace and an inherent part of implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on v1.10.12 of the SDK, I switched to v1.11.136 and that resolved my issue, add the code below, to your pom file

```
<!-- AWS S3 Dependencies-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.136</version>
    </dependency>
<!-- End of AWS S3 Dependencies -->
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to post more of the stack-trace so we can see at what point in the SDK lifecycle the exception is being generated (the stack-trace above only shows the apache classes). Can you also show how you're configuring the S3 client?

Are you configuring a custom `SocketFactory`? The check in question is looking to see if the `Socket` that the `SocketFactory` created is in fact an `SSLSocket` if not - that's where it bombs - you can see that from the Apache code [here](https://github.com/apache/httpclient/blob/4.5.x/httpclient/src/main/java-deprecated/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.java#L433).